# WorkflowScript: 19: Unknown stage section "stage". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

While running my Jenkins pipeline I am getting below error : org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 19: Unknown stage section "stage". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 19, column 5.

Try changing the indentation of of stage blocks.

Sample Code :

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
    ansiColor('xterm')
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
  }
  parameters {
    string(name: 'GIT_BRANCH', defaultValue: "${params.GIT_BRANCH}", description: 'checkout branch')
    choice(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', choices: ['staging', 'production'])
  }
  stages {
    stage('CI Build') {
      agent {
        kubernetes {
          yamlFile("jenkins/ci.yaml")
        }
      }
      stage('GitCheckout') {
        steps {
          script {
            updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins', state: 'running'
            checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${params.GIT_BRANCH}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "${params.GIT_BRANCH}"]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'wbfkjejkv86fnjdnfkgnde-341b26acc248', url: 'www@zzzz.yyyy.xx:xxx_xxxx/xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx.xxx']]]
            STAGING_IMAGE_TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "$(git rev-parse HEAD)"').trim()
          }
        }
      }
      stages {
        when {
          beforeAgent true
          allOf {
            expression { "${params.ENVIRONMENT}" == 'staging' }
          }
        }
        stage('Stage GitCheckout') {
          steps {
            script {
              updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins', state: 'running'
              checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${params.GIT_BRANCH}"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "${params.GIT_BRANCH}"]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'a2836a86-51b2-4c73-af15-341b26acc248', url: 'zzz@yyyyyy.xxxx.yyy:xxxx_yyy/ffff-wwww.xxx']]]
              STAGING_IMAGE_TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "$(git rev-parse HEAD)"').trim()
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Prepare Staging') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              sh "npm install"
              sh "npm run test"
              sh "npm run build:stage"
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Prepare Staging Docker') {
          steps {
            script {
              STAGING_IMAGE_TAG="${STAGING_IMAGE_TAG}-${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
              dockerImage = docker.build("${GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENDPOINT}/feedback-app-ui:${STAGING_IMAGE_TAG}")
              docker.withRegistry( GITLAB_REGISTRY_URL, GITLAB_REGISTRY_CREDS ) {
              dockerImage.push()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      stages {
        when {
          beforeAgent true
          allOf {
            expression { "${params.ENVIRONMENT}" == 'production' }
          }
        }
        stage('Prepare Production') {
          steps {
            container('node') {
              sh "npm install"
              sh "npm run test"
              sh "npm run build:prod"
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Prepare Production Docker') {
          steps {
            script {
              PROD_IMAGE_TAG="${PROD_IMAGE_TAG}-${params.ENVIRONMENT}"
              dockerImage = docker.build("${GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENDPOINT}/feedback-app-ui:${PROD_IMAGE_TAG}")
              docker.withRegistry( GITLAB_REGISTRY_URL, GITLAB_REGISTRY_CREDS ) {
              dockerImage.push()        
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }  
      post {
        always {
          script {
            notifyBuild(currentBuild.result, 'CI build status')
          }
        }
        failure {
          updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins', state: 'failed'
        }
        success {
          updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'jenkins', state: 'success'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your pipeline code to your question?

Comment: @VasilikiSiakka : The code is too long. How to add it ?

Comment: @VasilikiSiakka : I have added the code block

Comment: Error : org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 19: Unknown stage section "stage". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 19, column 5.
       stage('CI Build') {

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the "Build CI" stage doesn't contain any `steps`.

According to the [declarative pipeline documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stage):

> The stage directive goes in the stages section and **should contain a steps section**, an optional agent section, or other stage-specific directives.

You can check out the [sequential and parallel stages examples](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#sequential-stages) to see the proper syntax.

Lastly, jenkins doesn't always report the correct line for an error which makes debugging challenging. It's worth looking a few lines up and thinking "is jenkins trying to find the end of a block and failing to do so? Where would the beging of such block be?". That may help you find the line that's actually problematic.